# How to fix: Pytest "Create Test" dialog box won't open in Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, pytest

I'm trying to follow the tutorial on jetbrains (link: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/pytest.html) about using pytest in pycharm so I can work on test driven development. I'm stuck at the part where I'm supposed to create a test for a specific function in the Car.py module (found here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-and-running-your-first-python-project.html#) by hitting ctrl+shift+T and then clicking "Create new test...". 
[Screenshot of the step in the tutorial I'm stuck at.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4iYQ.png)

When I click "Create new test..." nothing happens. The dialog box which is supposed to pop-up does not appear.

I've gone to Settings>Tools>Python Integrated Tools and changed Default test runner to pytest like I'm supposed to. I checked packages in the Project Interpreter and pytest version 5.3.5 is there which I just installed. I restarted pycharm for good measure. Does anyone know why the dialog box might not be appearing? I'm sure there is a more manual approach to making the test file but the built-in pycharm ability to do this quicker/easier is preferable.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for answering your own question, you have given me an idea for my solution.
For what reason so ever, I was not providing PyCharm a root directory for my project so it was not recognising my files.
I changed it under:

```
Preferences > Project:"your project name" > Project Structure
```

Comment: This is what helped me solve the Create Test dialog box problem, as well as this other problem: I couldn't get gutter icons in my test files to use the standard test runner (pytest in my case).  It would always use the default python script runner. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It was a silly mistake in my case. I was not opening the proper project folder. Instead I was opening parent folder.

My hierarchy was
E:\Projects\SampleProject

Instead of opening SampleProject in PyCharm, I was opening Projects directory whole.

I think PyCharm will only open this if it recognizes valid structure of the project.

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to open the Settings window, go to `Project <project name>` > `Project Structure` and mark your source folders as `Sources` (highlighted as blue in my version of PyCharm). Then you should be able to create tests for them.